# Public variable won't update in typescript

Tags: typescript, variables

I have a class **HomePage {}** and inside it I have a plubic variable like this:

```
public resultado: any;
```

Also I have two methods and a function set up ike this, inside the same class.

```
l1() {
    this.l2();
}

l2() {
    l3();
    function l3(){
        this.resultado = "TEST";
    }
}
```

And it won't change the variable to TEST, like I don't have access to it even if public.

Answer (score 3):

What error are you getting? You should probably be getting

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'resultado' of undefined

... because `this` in `l3()` is referring to the function itself not the class. You need an arrow function or `bind()`.

```
l2() {
    const l3 = () => {
        this.resultado = "TEST";
    };

    l3();
}
```